# JQuery Date Picker how add id's to every day?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hello does someone know how I add id"s to every day in Datepicker?

Solutions I found so far don't match what I want to do.

Thank you

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1-s").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" , dayNamesMin: [ "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ],  defaultDate:'01.01.2019',  firstDay: 1 });
  });
```

Comment: fixed to get access over child selectors

Comment: <code><script>$(document).ready(function(){
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" , dayNamesMin: [ "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ],  defaultDate:'01.01.2020',  firstDay: 1 });
  });
  
  var August =31;
  setInterval(function(){ 
  var cv = $('#datepicker td:nth(10)').html();
  
  var datum = '03.01.2020';
  $('#datepicker td:nth(10)').css({ 'background-color':'red' });
  
  $('#cv').html(cv);
  },2000);
  
 });
</script>


</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="cv"></div>
 <br/><br/>
 <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body></code>

Comment: `code`<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $( function() { $( "#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" , dayNamesMin: [ "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ], defaultDate:'01.01.2020', firstDay: 1 }); }); var August =31; setInterval(function(){ var cv = $('#datepicker td:nth(10)').html(); var datum = '03.01.2020'; $('#datepicker td:nth(10)').css({ 'background-color':'red' }); $('#cv').html(cv); },2000); }); </script> </head> <body> <div id="cv"></div> <br/><br/> <div id="datepicker"></div> </body>`code`